# php 7 --with-config-file-scan-dir not working

Tags: php, linux, build, configuration, php-7

OS: Debian 8.6 amd64, PHP 7.0.13 source(tar.gz) download from php.net, checked the md5 and sha256.

Try `--with-config-file-scan-dir` set to `/etc/php7/cli/conf.d` or `/etc/php7/cli/conf.d/` still not working.

```sh
root@debian:/usr/src/php-7.0.13#./configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/php7 \
--with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/cli/conf.d/ \
--disable-all \
--enable-json=shared

root@debian:/usr/src/php-7.0.13# /usr/local/php7/bin/php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php7/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php7/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

In `/usr/src/php-7.0.13/main/build-defs.h` file last but one line, the `PHP_CONFIG_FILE_SCAN_DIR` constant was defined, but still not working.

```c
#define PHP_CONFIG_FILE_SCAN_DIR    "/etc/php7/cli/conf.d/"
```

If export the `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` environment variable, it's working.

```sh
root@debian:/usr/src/php-7.0.13# export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php7/cli/conf.d/
root@debian:/usr/src/php-7.0.13# /usr/local/php7/bin/php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php7/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php7/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php7/cli/conf.d/
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php7/cli/conf.d/json.ini
```

**Update**

When 1st building, I forget setting `--with-config-file-path` and `--with-config-file-scan-dir`, so I used `export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php7/cli/conf.d/` and it's working.

So I remove it and building again, But I used `export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=` NOT `unset`. So in the 2nd building, the `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` env variable is still working and it's empty.

The correct way

```sh
unset PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` is non-null in the environment, if it's going to be used:

```
krakjoe@fiji:/usr/src/php-src$ export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=
krakjoe@fiji:/usr/src/php-src$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php-cli.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

krakjoe@fiji:/usr/src/php-src$ export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php.d
krakjoe@fiji:/usr/src/php-src$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php-cli.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
```

Notice that the first execution exhibits the same symptoms you see.